# What is the best way to create a PDA account?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

Apparently creating PDA account is possible from both the client-side and the contract side. So I want to know what is the best way to create it. Are there any pros and cons on choosing the client side rather than the contract side or vice versa?

```
// client side
await PublicKey.createWithSeed(publicKey,SEED,new PublicKey(programId));

// contract side
system_instruction::create_account(&funding_account.key,&pda_account.key,lamports_required,ACCOUNT_DATA_LEN.try_into().unwrap(),&program_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off with the second option, since the first requires the `publicKey` keypair to sign the transaction, which will be much more limiting.

If you look at the instruction implementation, you'll see that `from` (the payer) and `base` (the key used to generate the account with seed) are both required as signers: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b2ece6368f4e2c2d63225c2fd30a0a19e7605ccd/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L557

With a PDA, you don't need *any* external signers at all. By proving how it derived the address, the program can "sign" for any PDA.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer. 
Apparently, anyone can create an account using `await PublicKey.createWithSeed` there is no restriction on who can sign the signature.

Comment: I clarified my answer